# Can't login after update 14.04 Secure Boot

Tags: 14.04, boot, secure-boot

After applying an update I'm not able to login in graphics mode.
The last update ask me about Secure Boot.
Now I can only login in command line mode. In graphics mode it keeps me asking the password again and again.
I tried to disable secure boot, and also to use mokutil --disable-validation but no success.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well..I've found out the following.

The last update affected to Secure Boot. It made propietary drivers not to work anymore (they are not signed) so one of the things I made through command line was to uninstall them and reinstall XOrg.

sudo apt-get purge "fglrx.*"

sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core

Probably the resintallation of XOrg affected to the following (I'm not sure)

The owner of the file .Xathority was root and not my user so that was the reason because it was stuck in that part.

I made the following:

sudo chown myusername:myusername .Xauthority

And the system is working again properly.

P.S. Thanks gsekse for trying to help.